# Get data from tcp listener callback in the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, proxy, server

I've created a transparent proxy for fixing the incoming data, but I want to have all the data from the listening callback in the main thread (where I've opened the socket). What's the best way to do it in the C#?

I am using the library [TrotiNet](http://trotinet.sourceforge.net/) plus some rewriting logic - fixing the response header. The simple code - as follows

```
using System;
using TrotiNet;

namespace TrotiNet.Example
{
    public class TransparentProxy : ProxyLogic
    {
        public TransparentProxy(HttpSocket clientSocket)
        : base(clientSocket) { }

        static new public TransparentProxy CreateProxy(HttpSocket clientSocket)
        {
            return new TransparentProxy(clientSocket);
        }

        protected override void OnReceiveRequest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-> " + RequestLine + " from HTTP referer " +
                RequestHeaders.Referer);
        }

        protected override void OnReceiveResponse()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("<- " + ResponseStatusLine +
            " with HTTP Content-Length: " +
            (ResponseHeaders.ContentLength ?? 0));
        }
    }

    public static class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int port = 12345;
            bool bUseIPv6 = false;

            var Server = new TcpServer(port, bUseIPv6);
            Server.Start(TransparentProxy.CreateProxy);

            Server.InitListenFinished.WaitOne();
            if (Server.InitListenException != null)
                throw Server.InitListenException;

            while (true)
            {
                //need to get the response data here
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            //Server.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

So mainly, I need to get all the data that comes to OnReceiveResponse in the main thread (Example.Main executor). I do such a proxy for one call - so data not more than 1kB.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Show code of connection initialization and manage, also every body needs to know code with you processing data in main thread, and what amount you want to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you fit in producer/consumer pattern, try to use BlockingCollection it support "Concurrent adding and taking of items from multiple threads"

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
BlockingCollection<Data> dataItems = new BlockingCollection<Data>(100);
```

in your dataReceiver handler do

```
dataItems.Add(data);
```

in your main thread consumer:

```
data = dataItems.Take();
```

*Also better to replace infinity loop with sleep to Console.Readkey()*

Comment: You've made my day! Thank you!